# I have 5 div's and I want them to fill the parent div on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have these 5 div's and I want them to fill the parent div on mouse hover I have these codes but they do not push the previous div (the div above) anywhere.

this is the HTML code:

```
<div id="photo">
<div id="no1">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="no2">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="no3">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="no4">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="no5">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
div#photo{
margin:10px 0;
padding:5px;
width:980px;
height:300px;
background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
border-radius:20px;
overflow:hidden;}

div#no1{
background-color:#FF00FF;}
div#no2{
background-color:#FF0;}
div#no3{
background-color:#00F;}
div#no4{
background-color:#0F0;}
div#no5{
background-color:#F00;}
div#no1, div#no2, div#no3, div#no4, div#no5{
width:970px;
height:61px;
transition:all 2s;}
div#no1:hover, div#no2:hover, div#no3:hover, div#no4:hover, div#no5:hover{
height:305px;}
```

Comment: make a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/)

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what you mean by "I have these 5 div's and I want them to fill the parent div on mouse hover"?

Comment: Do you have another site as an example? Not really sure what you are asking. What would this look like?

Comment: this is supposed to be like a slideshow, 5 different photos are shown in 5 61px lines, when you get your mouse over them, they open and fill the whole section! need to explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery `.mouseenter` & `.mouseleave` events to do your job.
here i made an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/y8GAR/26/)

Comment: this is exactly what I want, can you please tell me how to use the javascript section? where do I copy it?

Comment: @AminJafari See my example below for how to copy the javascript/jQuery into your document. Then, please select this answer (Eugen Halca's answer) as the correct answer as he has the correct jQuery solution.

Comment: where should I copy it? the <head> the <body> where? should I add anything? I tried everything, but it doesn't work! :(

Answer (score 1):

This is how to implement [Eugen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103983/4294399).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            div#photo {
                margin:10px 0;
                padding:5px;
                width:980px;
                height:300px;
                background-color:rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
                border-radius:20px;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            div#no1 {background-color:#FF00FF;}
            div#no2 {background-color:#FF0;}
            div#no3 {background-color:#00F;}
            div#no4 {background-color:#0F0;}
            div#no5 {background-color:#F00;}
            div#no1, div#no2, div#no3, div#no4, div#no5 {
                width:970px;
                height:61px;
                transition:all 2s;
            }
            .exp {height:305px;}
        </style>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $(".exp").mouseenter(function () {
                    $(".exp").not(this).stop();
                    $(this).prevAll().animate({
                        height: "0px"
                    }, 2000, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                    $(this).animate({
                        height: "305px"
                    }, 2000, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });

                });
                $(".exp").mouseleave(function () {
                    $(".exp").not(this).stop();
                    $(".exp").animate({
                        height: "61px"
                    }, 200, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                });
            
            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="photo">
        <div id="no1" class="exp">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="no2" class="exp">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="no3" class="exp">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="no4" class="exp">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="no5" class="exp">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually never used javascript or jquery, how can I use these functions? I write them in <script></script> in the <head></head> but it does nothing!

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/FEsIA)

I have used simple logic, Just applied height:0 to other div except the hovered div.

Answer (score 0):

Give every #noX id the same class, doesn't matter which name. For instance: .hoverPic.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.hoverPic').each(function(){ /*pick each element */

        $(this).hover(function(){ /* do something on hover */

            $(this).css({ /*set css value */
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%'
            });

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: I have never used javascript or jquery, and this code has a sintax error, which I don't know how to fix!

Answer (score -1):

you need to move the :hover selector to the parent and **apply the styles to that states children**. I'm not completely clear on your goal but this is how you would style it. Good luck and let me know if you need further help :)

```
div#photo:hover > div{
    height:305px;
}
```

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/59Uph/

**EDIT**

Try something along the lines of this
http://jsfiddle.net/59Uph/2/

Comment: in this way, all of the div's are getting the height 305px, I want just the one to get it, and I want it to fill the whole section given!